# Count event occurrence of row value A and row value B in same column in R or Python

Tags: python, r, loops

I am analyzing football matches. I want to know which teams have come from behind to draw a game or even win the game the most.

I have three columns:

1. Game ID
2. Teams
3. Minutes a particular team scored in a match

Here I put an example

```
GID <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
Teams <- c("Peru","Peru","Brazil","Brazil", "Chile", "Argentina","Argentina","Argentina","Colombia", "Ecuador", "Ecuador", "Colombia",
"Colombia")
Min_scores <- c(6,10,50,90,36,56,60,70,10,15,20,46,89)

df_example <- data.frame(GID,Teams,Min_scores)
df_example
```

In this case, there are three matches. Peru against Brazil, Chile against Argentina and Colombia against Ecuador.

In the first match Peru was winning 2-0 and Brazil came storming back and the game was tied at the end. In the second match, Argentina was loosing 1-0 and came back to win 3-1.. In the third example, Colombia started winning 1-0 then Ecuador turn the game around 2-1 and then Colombia turn the game again and finished winning 3-2.

In this case I want to count the times there are these changes of score where the loosing team starts winning or drawing the game. It could be a so called come from behind win or draw.

I've been thinking a lot about this but haven't come with an efficient solution. I think a loop could be a solution but there are a lot of matches and I am a bit worried it could be very slow.

Thank you very much for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)

df_example %>%
  group_by(GID) %>%
  arrange(GID, Min_scores) %>%
  mutate(key1 = ifelse(Teams == unique(Teams)[1], 1, -1)) %>%
  mutate(key2 = cumsum(key1)) %>%
  summarise(behind_win_or_draw = sum(key2 == 0))

    GID behind_win_or_draw
  <dbl>              <int>
1     1                  1
2     2                  1
3     3                  2
```

## Edit.

```
df_example %>%
  group_by(GID) %>%
  arrange(GID, Min_scores) %>%
  mutate(key1 = ifelse(Teams == unique(Teams)[1], 1, -1)) %>%
  mutate(key2 = cumsum(key1)) %>%
  filter(key2 == 0) %>%
  group_by(GID, Teams) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(key2 == 0))

    GID Teams         n
  <dbl> <chr>     <int>
1     1 Brazil        1
2     2 Argentina     1
3     3 Colombia      1
4     3 Ecuador       1
```

Comment: Thanks @Park, here you solved the problem of knowing how many come from behinds. The problem is knowing who were the ones that came from behind. In the example the answer would be Brazil (game 1 one time), Argentina (game 2 one time) and in game 3 Colombia (1 time), Ecuador (1 time).

Comment: @JuanCarlosSaravia I add the code above. Please check it out.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out in a couple of hours and let you know. In the meantime just for the sake of sharing I would recommend changing your pipes to the new |>. I know the widely used %>% still works but better get used to the new ones before they get the other one deprecated. I try the code with a bigger dataset and upvote immediately. Cheers.